# Adblock Plus list to block social networking elements

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock

I'm looking for an Adblock list that would block all the social network "sharing" links, Facebook Like buttons, Facebook iframes, Twitter counters, etc. Basically, all these social networking elements that slow down page load. Is there such a list? Otherwise, Disconnect seems to work fine but I'd rather use only one blocking extension.

Comment: this mozilla [kb](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1010872) *might* help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option, which works. Fanboy-list.

Add to Adblock the following list: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/fanboy-social.txt

You can test the effect on following website: http://obihoernchen.net/wordpress/770/plug_computer_arch_linux/

Answer (score 0):

1)An **Adblock subscription** available https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions at the bottom of the page named Antisocial which should remove most social media elements.

2)another one is **Fanboy Annoyance Block List** http://www.fanboy.co.nz/ which might also the  removes some social popups etc too.

3)Adblock Plus with **Element Hiding Helper** https://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper. Once the elements are blocked, there is a less chance for them to apear again.

4)The **Anti Social list** http://adversity.uk.to/ of Adblock to remove the annoying social buttons.

for more information http://www.techairlines.com/block-social-buttons-widgets/

Answer (score 0):

Tobias is correct. An easier way to add the social media elements blocker in Adblock Plus can be found here: https://adblockplus.org/en/features#socialmedia

Comment: Can you modify your answer to include detailed instructions, instead of just a link to an external site? Links rot.